# WinForms RichTextBox infinite horizontal scroll bug

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

A regular `RichTextBox` element placed on a form exhibits a bug wherein scrolling horizontally to the right with the mouse (horizontal scroll middle button or touch pad) keeps going forever and never stops. This is the case even if the `RichTextBox` contains only a single word that fits readily into its bounds and the scrollbars are disabled.

I've run into this bug since .NET 2.0 and assumed it would be fixed at some point, but I'm still seeing it on Windows 10 with .NET 4.6.

What's getting me is that I can't find any references to this here on SO or elsewhere on the internet.. Has anyone run into this before and does anyone know how to prevent this odd behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by .NET using an ancient version of the Win32 rich edit control that hasn't been updated in a decade+.

The solution was to override the version of the rich edit control that is created by overriding the `CreateParams` property and specifying a newer version instead:

```
public partial class BetterRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            LoadLibrary("MsftEdit.dll");

            //Use newer versions of the RTF control
            //Fixes a lot of bugs, such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/41233421/17027
            //A list of versions and their DLL paths can be found at https://github.com/dpradov/keynote-nf/issues/530
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.ClassName = "RichEdit50W";

            return createParams;
        }
    }
}
```